# Send value to Google Sheets via web app with formula in variable

Tags: javascript

I'm using a web app to send data to Google Sheets via Apps Script. I'm using 'appendrow' to post several variables. Everything works fine but one variable is a number, call it 'Amount'. I found out that I can type a Google Sheets type formula in my web app such as '=10-5', '=10*2', '=10/2' and when it gets posted to my Google Sheets it provides the expected result. Good! However, if I type '=10+5', I get an error in my Google Sheets. When I look at the formula bar, it shows '10 5'. Why does it not show the formula as '=10+5'? The previous examples that I gave all show the expected formula in the formula bar.

```
function doGet(e) {

  // I cannot take credit for this script. I copied and modified it from another user.

  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("FILE ID GOES HERE")
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Register"); //sheet name is 'Register'

  var date = e.parameter.date;
  e.parameter.date = '1/2/2023'
  var amount = e.parameter.amount;
  var paytype = e.parameter.paytype;
  var payid = e.parameter.payid;
  var maincat = e.parameter.maincat;
  var subcat = e.parameter.subcat;
  var explanation = e.parameter.explanation;

  sh.appendRow([date, amount, paytype, payid, maincat, subcat, 
  explanation]);

}
```

So when data get passed to Google Sheets via the sh.appendRow, the amount always works correctly when it contains, for example:

'10.52', '=10-5', '=10*2', '=10/2', but not '=10+5'. Instead, I get '10 5' and shows an error in the spreadsheet cell.

You may have guessed that I am a novice when it comes to script.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your current script and your sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: I've added my script and a little more information. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `'10.52', '=10-5', '=10*2', '=10/2', but not '=10+5'. Instead, I get '10 5' and shows an error in the spreadsheet cell.`. Can you provide the sample input value of `e` of `doGet(e)` and the sample output situation you expect as the image? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: Arigato gozaimasu. I'm going to take a class in Javascript and see if I can figure it out on my own. But I do appreciate your reaching out to help. BTW, watashi no kanai nihon jin desu.